# Django TemplateDoesNotExist when generating URL

Tags: python, html, django, url

I want to have my URL to change based on the results displayed.

For example, I want the URL to be .../profile_detail/1, but it always returns:

```
NoReverseMatch at /search/
Reverse for 'profile_detail' with arguments '(UUID('f3ef1f95-f374-4ac4-b1aa-b5db5fd76af7'),)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile_detail/(?P<profile_id>[0-9]+)/$']
```

views.py

```
def profile_detail(request, profile_id):
    user = get_object_or_404(CustomUser, pk=profile_id)
    return render(request, 'network/profile_detail.html', {'user': user})
```

models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    uniqueID = models.UUIDField(max_length=20, default=uuid.uuid4)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_("first name"), max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(_("last name"), max_length=100)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [first_name, last_name]

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Opening the uploaded image
        try:
            im = Image.open(self.image)

            output = BytesIO()

            # Resize/modify the image and convert to RGB from RGBA
            im = im.convert('RGB')
            im = im.resize((300, 300))

            # after modifications, save it to the output
            im.save(output, format='JPEG', quality=90)
            output.seek(0)

            # change the imagefield value to be the newly modified image value
            self.image = InMemoryUploadedFile(output, 'ImageField', "%s.jpg" % self.image.name.split('.')[0],
                                              'image/jpeg',
                                              sys.getsizeof(output), None)

        except:
            pass
        super(Profile, self).save()
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import SearchResultsView

urlpatterns = [
    path('feed', views.home, name="home"),
    path('', views.landing, name="landing"),
    path('about', views.about, name="about"),
    path('search/', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search'),
    path('profile_detail/<int:profile_id>/', views.profile_detail, name='profile_detail'),
]
```

search.html

```
{% block content %}

    <!-- Posts -->
    <div class="w3-card w3-margin-left w3-margin-right">
        <div class="w3-container w3-padding">
            <h4>Search Results</h4>
        </div>

        {% for user in object_list %}
            <a href="{% url 'profile_detail' user.uniqueID %}">
    .......
```

profile_detail.html

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="w3-card w3-margin-left w3-margin-right">
        <div class="w3-container w3-padding">
            <h1>User Profile</h1>
            <div>
                <h1>Profile information:</h1>
                {% if user.profile.image %}
                    <img src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}" height="150px"/>
                {% else %}
                    <img src="{% static 'images/avatar.svg' %}" height="150px"/>
                {% endif %}
    .....
```

The error get's already thrown when I try to access search, which should just list profiles and link them.

Where is the error?

Comment: I think you don't need a unique id because Django automatically add a unique id for every model

Comment: You are passsing a UID that is alphanumeric and in urls pattern is restricted it to integer. Which django is complaining about as it's trying to reverse to a path with uid.i think you can use profile models autogenerated id field to identify a profile instead of uid.

Comment: Thank you both, used the normal ID and now it works!